# Get different storage classes used in an S3 bucket

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudwatch

I'd like to retrieve different S3 storage classes used for an S3 bucket.

The result could look like:

```
{
    "MyS3BucketName": {
        "Standard": 3234 MB,
        "Glacier": 34624 MB,
        "StandardIA": 564 MB,
        ... For all retrieved storage types
    }
}
```

I noticed that Cloudwatch exposes a daily metric that I could use :

```
[ "AWS/S3", "BucketSizeBytes", "StorageType", "StandardStorage", "BucketName", ...]
[ "AWS/S3", "BucketSizeBytes", "StorageType", "GlacierStorage", "BucketName", ...]
```

But as I would like to execute my code over an AWS environment to track **all S3 buckets storage classes use**, making **one cloudwatch get-metric-data per storage type is quite consuming** (there are several  storage types : https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/metrics-dimensions.html#s3-cloudwatch-metrics).

Are there any way to get dynamically all the S3 storage types used **within a single request** ?

Many thanks in advance,

Pierre

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is loop over different storages classes like that:

```
for bucket in buckets:
    bucket_region: str = s3.head_bucket(Bucket=bucket["Name"])["ResponseMetadata"]["HTTPHeaders"]["x-amz-bucket-region"]

    cloudwatch = boto3.client(
        "cloudwatch",
        region_name=bucket_region,
        aws_access_key_id=AWS_ACCESS_KEY,
        aws_secret_access_key=AWS_SECRET_KEY,
        aws_session_token=AWS_SESSION_TOKEN,
    )

    # Define the storage types you're interested in
    storage_types = [
        "StandardStorage",
        "IntelligentTieringAAStorage",
        "IntelligentTieringAIAStorage",
        "IntelligentTieringDAAStorage",
        "IntelligentTieringFAStorage",
        "IntelligentTieringIAStorage",
        "StandardIAStorage",
        "StandardIASizeOverhead",
        "IntAAObjectOverhead",
        "IntAAS3ObjectOverhead",
        "IntDAAObjectOverhead",
        "IntDAAS3ObjectOverhead",
        "OneZoneIAStorage",
        "OneZoneIASizeOverhead",
        "ReducedRedundancyStorage",
        "GlacierInstantRetrievalSizeOverhead",
        "GlacierInstantRetrievalStorage",
        "GlacierStorage",
        "GlacierStagingStorage",
        "GlacierObjectOverhead",
        "GlacierS3ObjectOverhead",
        "DeepArchiveStorage",
        "DeepArchiveObjectOverhead",
        "DeepArchiveS3ObjectOverhead",
        "DeepArchiveStagingStorage",
    ]

    # Initialize a dictionary to hold the bucket sizes for each storage type
    storage_size = {storage_type: 0 for storage_type in storage_types}

    # Loop through each storage type and get the sum of BucketSizeBytes
    for storage_type in storage_types:
        response = cloudwatch.get_metric_data(
            MetricDataQueries=[
                {
                    "Id": "m1",
                    "MetricStat": {
                        "Metric": {
                            "Namespace": "AWS/S3",
                            "MetricName": "BucketSizeBytes",
                            "Dimensions": [
                                {"Name": "BucketName", "Value": bucket_name},
                                {"Name": "StorageType", "Value": storage_type},
                            ],
                        },
                        "Period": 24 * 60 * 60,  # You can adjust the period as needed
                        "Stat": "Sum",
                    },
                    "ReturnData": True,
                },
            ],
            StartTime=start_time,
            EndTime=end_time,
        )
        if response["MetricDataResults"][0]["Values"]:
            storage_size[storage_type] = response["MetricDataResults"][0]["Values"][0]

    print(storage_size)
```